# Why won't this extend method work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

```
function world_rat_head() {
    this.ext = function (obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Object) return $.extend(obj, this); 
    };
}
```

I want the result to be an extended object. How do I do it?

Comment: Your code gets `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name`. You should fix this first.

Comment: You need to give an actual example that shows the problem you're having. We have no idea how you're using that function, so we don't know how it's failing.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do `(obj instanceof Object)`. `$.extend` will silently do nothing if you try to extend a primitive.

Also, note that the first parameter to `$.extend` is what gets stuff added to it. If you intended for `$.extend` to modify `this`, then `this` needs to be the first parameter; otherwise, it's correct as you have it.

This should work, assuming `this` is an object you want to merge *onto* `obj`:

```
this.ext = function(obj) {
    return $.extend(obj, this);
}
// Test
var o = {a: 5};
console.log(this.ext(o));
```

If it doesn't work, log both `obj` and `this` and see if it does what you expect. Also, make sure that `this` isn't `window`.